# How can I eliminate floating point inaccuracy when I pack and unpack a floating point number?

Tags: perl, pack, unpack

I am packing an array of numbers to send via UDP to another piece of hardware using socket programming.

When I `pack` the number 12.2 and then `unpack` it, I get 12.199999892651. As I am working with numbers related to latitudes and longitudes, I cannot have such deviations.

This is the simple script I wrote:

```
use warnings;

use Time::HiRes qw (sleep);

@Data = ( 20.2, 30.23, 40.121, 1, 2, 3, 4, 6. 4, 3.2, 9.9, 0.1, 12.2, 0.99, 7.8, 999, 12.3 );

$myArr = pack('f*', @Data);

print "$myArr\n\n";

@Dec = unpack('f*',$myArr);

print "@Dec";
```

The output is:

```
20.2000007629395 30.2299995422363 40.1209983825684 1 2 3 4 6.40000009536743 3.20 000004768372 9.89999961853027 0.100000001490116 12.1999998092651 0.9900000095367 43 7.80000019073486 999 12.3000001907349
```

Is there any way I can control the precision?

Comment: I think you should split your second question into a separate post; it's not really related to the first question. It will be easier for future visitors to find answers that way.

Comment: 12.2 is a decimal number that is equal to 122/10. But it cannot be represented by the expression `m/(2**n)`, and therefore cannot be represented accurately using data types that rely on C's floating point types.  The precision is lost the moment your code experiences the number 12.2 -- internally there is no such thing as the floating point value 12.2.  We have similar problems in base-10, but have grown accustomed to them, so they don't surprise us.  An example would be expressing 1/3rd in decimal form: 0.33? Close by some measures, but not accurate.

Comment: Your array `@Data` is artificial. Ordinarily it will consist of text strings, not floating-point numbers. I think you need to send the text `"@Data"` instead of trying to pack the values as floating point. The "other end", whatever it is, can easily split the string on whitespace and recover exactly what was sent.

Comment: Please, ***always*** `use strict`, even in the most trivial of Perl programs

Comment: Thanks.. i will ask it as a Second question..  @ThisSuitIsBlackNot

Comment: Assuming you are dealing in latitudes and longitudes in degrees, on Earth, then the error between 12.2 and 12.199999892651, at the equator is 12mm.

Answer (score 7):

`pack`'s `f` template is for single-precision floating point numbers, which on most platforms is good to 7 or so decimal places of accuracy. The `d` template offers double-precision and will be good enough for ~15 decimal places.

```
print unpack("f", pack("f",12.2));          # "12.1999998092651"
print unpack("d", pack("d",12.2));          # "12.2"

printf "%.20f",unpack("f", pack("f",12.2)); # "12.19999980926513671875"
printf "%.20f",unpack("d", pack("d",12.2)); # "12.19999999999999928946"
```

Answer (score 4):

The short answer is: don't pack these numbers as floats. You will lose accuracy due to IEEE floating point representation. Instead, convert them to "character decimals" (i.e. strings), and pack them as strings. If you really need the accuracy, and don't need to perform math operations on them, you may want to store them as strings in Perl as well.

Comment: The Receiving hardware end can only accepts values... It cannot accept the strings

Comment: Then I think you are going to have to accept some loss of accuracy. You might try the "d" (double) pack format instead of "f".

Comment: @Asheesh: If the receiving end can accept only packed floating point then you are stuck with losing accuracy.

Comment: @Borodin Jinx. :)

Answer (score 1):

2/10 is a periodic number in binary just like 1/3 is a periodic number in decimal. It's impossible to store it exactly in a floating point number as it would take infinite storage.

As such, it's not `pack` that's introducing the error; it's faithfully storing precisely the number you provided it.

```
$ perl -E'say sprintf "%.20e", 12.2'
1.21999999999999992895e+01

$ perl -E'say sprintf "%.20e", unpack "d", pack "d", 12.2'
1.21999999999999992895e+01
```

As long as you use floating point numbers, you will not be able to store 12.2 exactly.

But as you can see above, you can store store precisely enough by using `d` (double-precision, almost 16 digits of precision) instead of `f` (single-precision, over 7 digits of precision). Perl uses double-precision, so you were actually introducing precision loss by using `f` instead of `d`.

So use `d`, and round your results (`sprintf "%.10f"`).